# How to hide something when clicking again the div (already opened)

Tags: jquery

I've a jQuery code that makes a menu display or hide depending on the click of another element. Right now my problem is how to make the same div button toggle display and hide if clicked successively?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCB5W/)

```js
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = new Array();
    container.push($('#item_1'));
    container.push($('#item_2'));
    
    $.each(container, function(key, value) {
        if (!$(value).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && $(value).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            $(value).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.item_1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}

.item_2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$('#item_1').toggle();">Open 1</button>
<label id="item_1" class="item_1">Text 1</label>
<button onclick="$('#item_2').toggle();">Open 2</button>
<label id="item_2" class="item_2">Text 2</label>
```

Expected: Closing the MENU when clicking again the button (it is an `a href`)
Actual: Clicking the same `a href` only hides the menu.

Comment: Thanks, sorry it was that i tried before looking the new guide and the "code" section but i wasn't able to do it. I even tried using the Quote code but i wasn't able.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First off, adding a common class (item) to the items makes them easy to select.
- Changing the inline bindings to have a data field lets us relate the buttons to the labels easily
- Then we can change the logic to hide anything that is not the target
- And finally calling toggle on the target will show/hide it in turn

```js
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
  var $items = $('.item');
  var $target = $('#'+ $(e.target).data('target'));
  
  $items.not($target).hide();
  $target.toggle();
});
```

```css
.item_1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}

.item_2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-target="item_1">Open 1</button>
<label id="item_1" class="item item_1">Text 1</label>
<button data-target="item_2">Open 2</button>
<label id="item_2" class="item item_2">Text 2</label>
```